# Converter um array de floats para integer

Tags: python, array, python-2.7, conversão-de-tipo, numpy

Suponha o seguinte:

```python
import numpy as np

a = np.array ( [1.1, 2.2, 3.3] )
```

Como converter esse array pra `int` sem ter que iterar cada elemento ou usando mais um array?

Por que fazer:

```python
b = int(a)
```

Dá um erro, porque só é possível converter um array de comprimento 1 pra `int`. Então tento:

```python
for i in a:
    int(i)
    # ou
    # i = int(i)
```

não resolve, porque `a`, depois do loop permanece com os elementos em float.

Teria então que usar mais um array pra fazer isso e iterar sobre esse array:

```python
b = np.zeros( a.shape )
for i in xrange(0, len(a))
    b[i] = int(a[i])
```

Me devolve um array com os números inteiros, sim, mas ainda do tipo `float`, note o ponto...

```python
print b
[1., 2., 3.]
```

Como então converter para int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os arrays do tipo `numpy.ndarray` tem um método para conversão de tipo:

```python
import numpy as np

a = np.array( [1.1, 2.2, 3.3] )
b = a.astype('int')
print b
[1, 2, 3]
```

Deve-se tomar cuidado, contudo, ao lidar com arrays muito grandes, já que o `astype` cria uma cópia do array em memória.

Comment: se for um array unidimensional, você pode fazer: b = map(int, a). Mas isso não funcionará para arrays multidimensionais.

Answer (score 6):

Tente isto:

```python
a = array( [1.1, 2.2, 3.3] )
b = array(a, 'int')
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ? TypeError: Array can not be safely cast to required type

b = a.astype(Int)
```

Comment: não entendi sua resposta... podes elaborar melhor? Parece que o que sugeres para tentar, diferente da minha outra resposta, também dá erro e terminas fazendo o mesmo...

Comment: Sim porém tem uma opção a mais, caso .astype() não resolva, o que pode ocorrer, não sei porque, mais comigo ja aconteceu e após fazer desta forma não tive mais problemas com isso...

Comment: podes explicar melhor sua resposta? Estou tendo dificuldades em entender como o erro que você apresenta é relevante...

Comment: Se houve algum erro é por que a primeira forma não deu certo, ai sim neste caso eu uso o .astype()...

Comment: Hum! Agora sim! Compreendido.

Comment: corrigi o `Int`, que não existe me python (2.7 ao menos), e troquei por `'int'`. Mas não consegui reproduzir o erro que mostraste.

Comment: Ele não tem que necessariamente ocorrer, é uma prevenção caso ocorra, pois pode ser que ocorra, não descobri o por que, mais quando ocorreu consegui resolver da forma que coloquei....

Answer (score 4):

Acho que uma iteração por lista já resolve o seu problema sem precisar do astype.

Utilizando [compressão de lista](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista#Python) é possível realizar essa conversão de forma bem mais simples:

```
a = [1.1,2.2,3.3]
b = [int(x) for x in a]
```

O resultado de `print b` será:

```
>>[1, 2, 3]
```

Claro que isso só valerá se forem elementos válidos para se converter, caso existam elementos inválidos (que não podem ser convertidos para o tipo integer), será retornado uma exceção. No caso o ideal seria utilizando um bloco `try\except`, caso você não tenha certeza dos elementos da lista:

```
a = [1.1,2.2,3.3]
try:
  b = [int(x) for x in a]
except:
  print 'Nao foi possivel converter o numero.'
```

Comment: Muito interessante! E aprendi a utilizar compressão de lista por conta da sua contribuição. Mas me parece que essa solução é mais custosa do que o astype, não? Não implica iteração pela lista, ou coisa assim?

Comment: Confirmado. Usando timeit, o astype faz a conversão de um array de 200 posições em `0.010539054870605469` enquanto a compressão de lista o faz em `0.2911491394042969`, na minha máquina. O ponto é: o astype é mais rápido. E tenho que escrever menos...

Comment: Daí vai mais das possibilidades, se você pode usar uma lib, no caso a numpy, é sim uma solução melhor, só que a compreensão de lista já é suportado pela própria linguagem. Enfim, pelo menos a resposta serviu pra alguma coisa. (:

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma alternativa, usando `map`:

```
map(int, [1.2, 2.1, 3.1])
```

O `map` aplica a função passada no primeiro parâmetro em cada elemento da lista do segundo parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Os arrays de numpy têm um tipo associado, e o default é `float`. Para criar um array de ints, você invariavelmente vai ter que criar um `array` novo. Por outro lado, isso é bastante fácil:

```
b = np.array( a, dtype=np.int32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra algum valor ser válido pra transformar em int, ele tem que ser um "praticamente int".

é só separar a parte inteira da parte decimal:

```
int = float - (float % 1);
```

(Não sei como é mod em python, acredito que seja %.)

Answer (score 0):

O método `array` da classe `numpy` suporta ao todo **6** tipos de parâmetros. Dentre esses parâmetros temos o `dtype`. Este, por sua vez, serve para identificar o tipo de dados desejado para o objeto `array`.

[Veja aqui](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html?highlight=array#numpy.array) maiores detalhes.

Desse modo podemos implementar um algoritmo que converta todos os elementos para o tipo `int`. Este algoritmo é...

```
from numpy import array

a = array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3])
b = array(a, int)
print(b)
```